# Magento sample order checkout

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1, orders, checkout

In my site there are products like curtains and customer can choose different color for curtains, for color we are using custom options so customer can choose different color, but there are we have requirement that customer can order sample color to look and feel before buying actual product, so how we can give sample order functionality.

Colors are not actual product so we can't use magento checkout functionality but if customer order sample product then how we can handle this sample order?

Looking for great idea from magento folks.

Comment: I suppose a sample is a piece of curtain in given color, a free product that needs to be delivered to the customer. What exactly is stopping you from setting it up as such and using Magento checkout?

Comment: Client don't want to create products as there are may be thousands of color and styles available for product and we are in mid that we create functionality for choosing style and color for given product

Comment: I used this extension [Product Sample Order](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/31272/s/product-sample-order/) this is seems good to me.

Comment: For magento 1: https://mage-people.com/product/product-sample-order/    and  for magento 2: https://mage-people.com/product/sample-order-extension-for-magento-2/   you can try. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an idea!

Can you add one extra custom option to the product, a "Sample product" check box with -100 percent price adjustment. By checking the check box customer turn the product into a sample.

Everything is in sync, client doesn't need to create products, and you can use Magento checkout functionality from there on.

Comment: Ohh wow nice idea, let me try

Comment: Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

why not you are using this https://mage-people.com/product/magento-sample-order-extension/ as it has a simple solution.  thanks